# Problem using Include() when serializing Entity Framework 4 POCO classes with WCF

Tags: entity-framework, serialization, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, poco

I have a WCF service with an Entity Framework 4 model, using POCO classes that are serialized and sent over to client applications. I have `LazyLoadingEnabled` and `ProxyCreationEnabled` set to `false`, and I'm using Linq to Entites to query an Entity, and return it via `List<>` to the client. Everything goes perfect when I don't use Include():

```
public List<TBLTable1> GetTBLTable1(string pCode)
{
  using (PcFactoryEntities oPcFactoryDB = new PcFactoryEntities())
  {
    oPcFactoryDB.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    oPcFactoryDB.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var oRS = oPcFactoryDB.TBLTable1
      .Where(c => c.Code == pCode).ToList();
    XmlObjectSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TBLTable1));
    serializer.WriteObject(new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented }, oRS[0]);
    return oRS;
  }
}
```

After the Linq query, I use the serializer to simulate the serialization process that happens when the POCO class is sent to the client, and I works great. However, when I add an Include() to load one of the navigation list for the class, it starts serializing all of `Table2`'s navigation's list as if LazyLoadingEnabled was set to true, and it goes on forever serializing probably the whole database!

```
public List<TBLTable1> GetTBLTable1(string pCode)
{
  using (PcFactoryEntities oPcFactoryDB = new PcFactoryEntities())
  {
    oPcFactoryDB.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    oPcFactoryDB.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var oRS = oPcFactoryDB.TBLTable1
      .Include("TBLTable2")
      .Where(c => c.Code == pCode).ToList();
    XmlObjectSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TBLTable1));
    serializer.WriteObject(new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented }, oRS[0]);
    return oRS;
  }
}
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the LazyLoadingEnabled set to false apply to the class included manually and return all of it's navigation lists to `null` as it happens with all of the other navigation lists for `Table1`? Is there a way to fix this so I can return with Table1 some navigations lists filled in with their navigation lists set to `null`? 
Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to directly serialize the entity, try projecting to a DTO and serializing that. I agree what your seeing is bizarre behaviour - but it could be that the EF internal graph is taking over when your serializing the entities, but if you serialize a DTO, EF should not intervene.

E.g:

```
var dto = oPcFactoryDB.TBLTable1
                      .Where(x => x.Code == pCode)
                      .Select(x => new SpecialisedDTO
                      {
                         PropertyOne = x,
                         PropertyTwo = x.TBLTable2
                      }).ToList();
```

And then serialize that.

Since your projecting, you don't need to eager load - EF will grab what it needs to based on the query you have provided.

It's usually good practice in N-Tier situations to transmit DTO's over the wire, rather than the pure POCO entities.

Comment: Thanks for the input, and it is a valid work around for my problem, but I would really like to know if this is a EF bug, if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm just missing something. Tks

Comment: I'm looking into your proposed solution. How would I declare the SpecialiseDTS class? I'd have a property PropertyOne of type TBLTable1? Tks for your time

Comment: Yes, two properties with get/sets - PropertyOne of type TBLTable1, and PropertyTwo of type TBLTable2

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Navigation Property on TBLtable1 to TBLtable2?  The .Include() is used to include entities that are linked va FK relationships and the .Include() is passed the Name of the Navigation Property.

So if you have a Person Entity with a NavigationProperty to an Addresses Entity called PersonAddresses you would then execute the following in order to get the Person and their addresses.

```
var p = dbContext.Person
         .Where(x => x.Id == id)
         .Include("PersonAddresses")
         .SelectFirstOrDefault;
```

Comment: Tks Shayne. I do have a navigation property, and the include is working. The problem is the serialization of the object goes crazy when I use Include, despite the Lazy Loading being disabled. Tks